# Duplicate Tab Python when printing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good afternoon,

i am doing the course from freeCodeCamp.org : Algorithmic Trading Using Python - Full Course

i have problem with the below code :

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import requests

import xlsxwriter

import math

stocks = pd.read_csv(r'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.csv')

from secret import IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN

my_columns=['Ticker','Stock Price','Market Capitalisation','Number of Shares to Buy']

final_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = my_columns)

for stock in stocks['Ticker'][:5]:

   api_url =f'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{stock}/quote?token={IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN}'

   data = requests.get(api_url).json()

   final_dataframe = final_dataframe.append(

   pd.Series([stock,data['latestPrice'],data['marketCap'],'N/A'],

index= my_columns),ignore_index=True)

   print(final_dataframe)
```

it print me the below :

[result wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMWPf.png)

i would like to have only as in the exercise the below:

[result wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNDUb.png)

Does someone have an idea where it is wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suggest you put your `print(final_dataframe)` outside the for loop, could you try it please thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just had been printing your `final_dataframe` for every iteration when your `pd.Series` is being `appended` . You can put the `print(final_dataframe)` outside the for loop & it should work just fine as in the output that you wanted.

```
for stock in stocks['Ticker'][:5]:

   api_url =f'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{stock}/quote?token={IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN}'

   data = requests.get(api_url).json()

   final_dataframe = final_dataframe.append(

   pd.Series([stock,data['latestPrice'],data['marketCap'],'N/A'],index= my_columns),ignore_index=True)


print(final_dataframe)
```